# Entity Framework - Parent Child relational table

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have an Organization entity table

```
public class Organization
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public int OrganizationTypeId { get; set; } 
    public OrganizationType OrganizationType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrganizationRelation> OrganizationRelations { get; set; }        
}
```

then I have my relational table with a self-referencing parent column

```
public class OrganizationRelation
{
    public int OrganizationRelationId { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }        
    public int? ParentOrganizationId { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public Organization ParentOrganization { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationRelationModelConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<OrganizationRelation>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<OrganizationRelation> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.OrganizationRelationId);
        builder.Property(c => c.OrganizationRelationId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(c => c.OrganizationId).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(c => c.ParentOrganizationId);            
        builder.HasOne(r => r.Organization).WithMany().HasForeignKey(fk => fk.OrganizationId);
        builder.HasOne(r => r.ParentOrganization).WithMany().HasForeignKey(fk => fk.ParentOrganizationId);
        builder.ToTable("OrganizationRelation", "dbo");
    }
}
```

When I deploy my db with migration, I see this table created:

```
CREATE TABLE [mdo].[OrganizationRelation](
[OrganizationRelationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrganizationId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ParentOrganizationId] [int] NULL,
[OrganizationId1] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrganizationRelation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[OrganizationRelationId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I'm using EF 5.0
I don't get it why is creating the column OrganizationId1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't map `OrganizationRelation.ParentOrganization` to `Organization.OrganizationRelations`, so EF is adding an additional FK to `OrganizationRelation` for the second navigation property.

But that model seems overly complex.  Why not just

```
public class Organization
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentOrganizationId { get; set; }
    public Organization ParentOrganization { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Organization> ChildOrganizations{ get; } = new HashSet<Organization>();
}
```

which creates

```
  CREATE TABLE [Organization] (
      [OrganizationId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
      [Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [OrganizationTypeId] int NOT NULL,
      [ParentOrganizationId] int NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_Organization] PRIMARY KEY ([OrganizationId]),
      CONSTRAINT [FK_Organization_Organization_ParentOrganizationId] FOREIGN KEY ([ParentOrganizationId]) REFERENCES [Organization] ([OrganizationId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION
  );

  CREATE INDEX [IX_Organization_ParentOrganizationId] ON [Organization] ([ParentOrganizationId]);
```

?

To factor a foreign key out into a separate table,  you just introduce a 1-1 dependent table, where the dependent table's FK and PK are the same as the main table's PK.

So to do the same thing with a separate entity would look like this:

```
public class Organization
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationTypeId { get; set; }
    public OrganizationRelation OrganizationRelation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrganizationRelation> ChildOrganizations { get; } = new HashSet<OrganizationRelation>();
}
public class OrganizationRelation
{
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public int ParentOrganizationId { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public Organization ParentOrganization { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<OrganizationRelation>().HasKey(c => c.OrganizationId);

    builder.Entity<OrganizationRelation>()
           .HasOne(r => r.Organization)
           .WithOne(o => o.OrganizationRelation)
           .HasForeignKey(nameof(OrganizationRelation), nameof(OrganizationRelation.OrganizationId));

    builder.Entity<OrganizationRelation>()
           .HasOne(r => r.ParentOrganization)
           .WithMany(o => o.ChildOrganizations)
           .HasForeignKey(r => r.ParentOrganizationId)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    builder.Entity<OrganizationRelation>().ToTable("OrganizationRelation", "dbo");


    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to have a separate table, that's why I keep it out

Comment: Ok.  So can an Organization have many parents or only many children?

Comment: An organization can have many children

Comment: See updated answer.